# Uso de comandos no R e correções de erro

Tags: r

Tenho uma base de dados grande 1800 linhas e 50 colunas.

Dessas 50 colunas 3 delas (Densidade, Biomassa e BMI) são respostas. Devo comparar uma a uma com as outras variáveis. Estou fazendo testes de normalidade, ANOVA, Tukey etc. Uma análise exploratória para descrever o comportamento entre elas. Tem uma pessoa me ajudando mas gostaria de resolver alguns problemas que as vezes me impedem de seguir em frente sozinho e às vezes essa pessoa está muito ocupada. Outro detalhe é que sou iniciante, mas entusiasta agora com o `R`.

***VAMOS AO PROBLEMA....***

Faço todos os testes com Densidade (pelo menos 10) e quando mudo a variável resposta por Biomassa o `R` me retorna com as ocorrências da Densidade. 
Criamos um subset para as outras variáveis resposta (Biomassa e BMI). 
Mas ai entra o problema: em alguns casos tenho variáveis que têm menos de 1% de participação nos dados e além disso um "N" inferior a 5.

Preciso retirar isso da análise e não sei como fazer no subset criado.
No caso da primeira variável resposta (Densidade) usamos o comando:              `%in%` C ("variável a ser retirada da análise")
contudo no caso do subset o script muda e não sei inserir esse comando ou outro.

Comment: Oi Herlon, coloque o código que está usando para fazer isso. Da forma como está sua pergunta está difícil de responder objetivamente. Você precisa dar uma olahda nisso daqui e entender como funciona o subsetting no R. http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html

Comment: Prezado Daniel, obrigado pela sua disposição em tentar me ajudar e peço desculpas pelo "atropelo" nas informações, realmente fiz a pergunta no momento em que estava querendo resolver o problema. Vamos ver se consigo ser mais claro agora, vou numerar. 1 - minha base tem 1700 linhas e 50 colunas (variáveis); 2 - dessas 50 variáveis da base 3 delas devo usar como resposta. 4 - Portanto faço os primeiros testes com a variável resposta 1 e tudo que quero testar (10 outras variáveis pelo menos); 5 - quando passo para a variável 2 e depois a 3 é que crio os subsets, mas ai o R usa tudo da variável 1

Comment: Ou seja, variável 1 tenho 1700 dados, variável 2 e 3, menos de 1000. Espero que consiga entender agora. Obrigado